# On a step in Egorov's measure theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am in the midst of proving the following

**Theorem**
Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of measurable functions converging almost everywhere to a function $f$ on a measurable set $E\subset [0,1]=\Omega$. Then given any $\delta >0$ there exists a measurable set $E_{\delta} \subset E$ where the convergence is uniform on (as well as some other conditions but I dont care to write them as they do not pertain to my question).

I will write out the first few lines of the proof to where I have a question.

**Proof**
The function $f$ is measurable since it is the limit of a sequence of measurable functions that converges almost everywhere (we are tacitly assuming our measure $\mu$ is complete). Let
$$E_n^m=\bigcap_{i>n} \left\{x\in \Omega : |f_i(x)-f(x)|<\frac{1}{m}\right\}.$$
Moreover, let 
$$E^m=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n^m.$$
It follows that
$$E_1^m \subset E_2^m \subset \dotso, $$
and hence, by the continuity theorem of $\mu$, we have given any $\delta >0$, there is a $n_0(m)$ such that
$$\mu(E^m\setminus E_{n_0(m)}^m) < \frac{\delta}{2^m}.$$

(The continuity theorems are if $A=\cup_n A_n$ where $A_n$ are measurable and increasing in the sense that $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \dotso$ then $\mu(A)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \mu(A_n)$, and a similar statement and conclusion for decreasing sets and their intersection.)

I don't understand how they are exactly applying the continuity theorem to the increasing sequence at hand to get $\mu(E^m\setminus E_{n_0(m)}^m) < \frac{\delta}{2^m}.$ I know it follows, by applying the theorem, that we may make,
$$|\mu(E_n^m)-\mu(E^m)|<\epsilon$$
given any $\epsilon$, for sufficiently large $n$. Can one deduce the above bound by this one? I feel like it is a fairly small thing I am missing here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a fixed $m$ the sequence $E^m\setminus E^m_k \downarrow \emptyset$, when $k\to\infty$.

Comment: @Leandro ah crap thats what it was!!!! Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome.